# Redux Hot Reload Warning on changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, hot-module-replacement

I get the following warning when I try to update any of my react components...

> Provider does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.

As far as I can tell, my code looks like the instructions, but I still get the warning.

***client.js***

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import createStore from '../shared/store/createStore';

import routes from '../shared/routes';

const store = createStore(window.__app_data);
const history = browserHistory;

if (window.__isProduction === false) {
    window.React = React; // Enable debugger
}

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}

render (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content')
)
```

***configureStore.js***

```
'use strict';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import { selectSubreddit, fetchPosts } from '../actions'

export default function createReduxStore(initialState = {}) {
    const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));    

    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextReducer = require('../reducers').default;
            store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
        });
    }

    return store;
};
```

***Server.js***

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../../webpack.config.dev';

let compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    hot: true,
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
```

Is there something I'm missing? Here is a link to the full [Github Repo](https://github.com/Mr-Antivirus/Riur) if you want to see the full src.

[Edited] Added server.js and github link.

Comment: I see two places where you are calling createStore, could your issue be you want to use the createReduxStore function? `const store = createReduxStore(window.__app_data);`

Comment: Actually the "createStore" in client.js is the createReduxStore function. I just named it differently in the client.

Comment: oh ok I just saw configureStore.js and saw its not the same name so I figured it wasn't the same one. have you tried debugging the create part where you setup the accept function? and where you call it?

Comment: Truthfully, I'm not sure how to. I tried doing a console.log and passing in store.getState, but the state doesn't look like it changed between hot reloads.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I have a feeling you're going to tell me to get redux-devtools, so I'll get the extension now.

Comment: Nope I wasn't actually :) in the areas you want to pause on a breakpoint just type `debugger;` and when you load the page make sure you have the dev tools open. aka right click on the page and say inspect element. Debugging is super useful :)

Comment: just a hunch, module.hot doesn't look like its configured properly and isn't true. that would make this not work properly but I dont know without seeing your setup :)

Comment: Hey John, a link to the full src is posted at the bottom of the question. Webpack/redux/hot reloading is new to me, so I'm pretty sure thats probably the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. There were multiple changes needed.

1. Remove module.hot code from ***client.js*** (Hot reloading that file caused Redux and React-Router warnings.
2. Create an index file for my React page components to export from.
3. Add module.hot code to newly created index file.
4. Change all React components to classes. const Page = () => () doesn't re-render with hot reloading.

After making those changes, everything started to work properly and I get no more warnings :-)